# What does it mean when one .Swift file's icon is darker than another's?

Tags: xcode, swift

Notice that in the picture, one .Swift file's icon is darker than the other's. Why is that?

[image: Notice that in the picture, one .Swift file's icon is darker than the other's. Why is that?]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It means you have unsaved changes (in the darker file).

Comment: Thank you. Drove me nuts for a while!

Comment: I have not been actively saving anything between xcode sessions in the last two months, but I'm not aware of any lost work. Does xcode automatically save all unsaved files when xcode is closed?

Comment: It took me a while to search for this answer. If this is the case, why does the Xcode docs say that Xcode automatically saves and keeps track of documents? How can I enable autosave so that I never have darker icons?

Comment: Xcode autosaves at least as frequently as 1) when you build/run and 2) when you quit Xcode.  It may save on other events but those are the two main cases I'm familiar with.  Of course you can always press cmd-s to save a specific document or cmd-opt-s to save all documents.  These days Xcode is very stable so it's not something worth worrying about, but if it really bothers you it's easy to develop the habit of pressing cmd-s as a final keystroke after you've written some new code.